# Returning Value from HTTP Response in Java

Tags: java, json, spring

I'm having an issue getting a value while using a ResponseEntity. In simplest terms, after making an API call and using

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = *api call*
String value = response.getBody();
```

I get as an output

```
{"value":123456}
```

However I would like to have the string: value be equal to just 123456 without simply brute forcing it. Any Ideas on how to do so?

Comment: Don't ask for a ResponseEntity<String>. Ask for a ResponseEntity<YourClassMappingThisJsonObject>. If youposted your code, it would be much easier to explain how to modify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use string as the generic of the `ResponseEntity` object.
Create your own object like this:

```
public class MyResponse {
    private String value;

    public String getValue () {
        return this.value;
    }

    public void setValue (String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

And then use this object like this:

```
ResponseEntity<MyResponse> response = *api call*
String value = response.getBody().getValue();
```

Comment: I would suggest this approach

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour is normal since your ResponeEntity is wrapping a String.

You should rather use a class that defines an attribute `value`.

Assuming you have a class `MyClass` that defines the attribute `value` (with proper getter), all you have to do is to change your code as follows :

```
ResponseEntity<MyClass> response = *api call* 

String value = response.getBody().getValue();
```